# Accessing a class from a different file without #including it?

Tags: c++, class, header, include, circular-dependency

I got stuck on an issue that required one class with a pointer to another class, which had a pointer to the other class, i.e:

File 1:

```cpp
class A
{
    B* b;
};
```

File 2:

```cpp
class B
{
    A* a;
};
```

i had a look at the github repo and it seemed like they were able to access a class 'Actor' without including it. How is this possible? [Here is the repo for a reference](https://github.com/gameprogcpp/code/blob/master/Chapter08/Component.h)

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>

class Component
{
public:
    // Constructor
    // (the lower the update order, the earlier the component updates)
    Component(class Actor* owner, int updateOrder = 100);
    // Destructor
    virtual ~Component();
    // Update this component by delta time
    virtual void Update(float deltaTime);
    // Process input for this component
    virtual void ProcessInput(const struct InputState& state) {}
    // Called when world transform changes
    virtual void OnUpdateWorldTransform() { }

    int GetUpdateOrder() const { return mUpdateOrder; }
protected:
    // Owning actor
    class Actor* mOwner;
    // Update order of component
    int mUpdateOrder;
};
```

Comment: if you look at the file i linked from a repo, which was made by the author of the book i am currently reading, they are not using a forward declaration.

Comment: They apparently expect every source file that includes `Component.h` to include `Actor.h` first. This is poor desgin.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - They don't.

Comment: `class Actor* owner` is kind of a forward declaration, see [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier).

Comment: ahh thanks @Evg, I didn't know that